# Excel VBA Loop That Not Stops Based On Activecell Value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a loop that needs to stop when activecell value is "BBSE", but it passes the cell and continues the loop. someone can help me with that?
I cut rows from table in one workbbok and paste it to another. before the list in column F I have many blank cells, and because of that I am usind xldown.
Here is the relevant code:

```
'Illuminators Worksheet
OP_wb.Activate
Range("F2").End(xlDown).Select


Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "BBSE"
    OP_wb.Activate
    Worksheets("Optic Main").Activate
    Range("F2").End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Cut
    Demand_WB.Activate
    Worksheets("Illuminators").Activate
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste


Loop
```

Here is where I want to stop the loop in the red circle:

[image]

this is why I am using END.xlDown

[image]

Comment: This will never match, as you are trying to match the content of a column, against that of a single cell.

Comment: But your `ActiveCell` is in column A! (and on a different sheet? and in a different workbook??)  (except for the first time through the loop)

Comment: Basically, stop using `Activate` and `Select`.  See  https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/6535336.

Comment: @Luuklag The first time through the loop, the single cell represented by something like `OP_wb.ActiveSheet.Range("F2").End(xlDown)` is selected (I'm guessing `OP_wb` is a workbook).  After that the single cell represented by `Demand_WB.Worksheets("Illuminators").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)` is selected.  So it is never a column that is selected.  (I think.  Maybe I should check.)  No, you were right, an entire row is selected on the second time through.

Comment: @YowE3K I thought that `Range("F2").End(xlDown).Select` is an entire column. I assumed the matching should occur here, because he obviously wants to stop cutting rows when he meets the next header row. So I think implementing a loop here would work best.

Comment: @Luuklag Argh - I get confused by ActiveCell and Select and Selection!!  It appears that the `ActiveSheet.Paste` makes the **`Selection`** the entire row on the destination sheet, but the **`ActiveCell`** remains at the cell selected by `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select` - so my very first comment was correct after all.

Comment: @YowE3K So he is checking against this value, on a sheet that he doesn't want to contain the value he is checking against. Just don't use a `Do While` loop I guess.

Comment: I am having difficulties understanding what the code is trying to do.  Is it trying to copy the information from sheet "Optic Main" in `OP_wb` to sheet "Illuminators" in `Demand_WB` in reverse order (i.e. bottom row ends up at the top) until you reach the source row containing "BBSE" in column F?

Comment: I have blanks in F before the cells I select, because of that I am using xldown.

Comment: So, you want to find the first non-blank cell in column F, and copy the entire rows from there until the row containing "BBSE".   That sounds like a job for `Find` and then one single copy statement.

Comment: @YowE3K - excatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to achieve correctly, I believe the following will achieve it:

```
Dim startRow As Long
Dim endRow As Long
With OP_wb.Worksheets("Optic Main")
    startRow = .Range("F2").End(xlDown).Row
    endRow = .Columns("F").Find(What:="BBSE", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
    .Rows(startRow & ":" & endRow).Cut
End With
With Demand_WB.Worksheets("Illuminators")
    .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

May be try like this...

```
'Mentioning Starting Row Here
x = 2

Do
    'x refers to Row and F refer to column name
    With Cells(x, "F")
        'Exiting Do Loop once it finds the matching value using If statement
        If .Value = "BBSE" Then Exit Do
        OP_wb.Activate
        Worksheets("Optic Main").Activate
        .EntireRow.Cut
        Demand_WB.Activate
        Worksheets("Illuminators").Activate
        Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End With
    'Incrementing row number here to move on to next row
    x = x + 1
Loop
```

Comment: End if is not needed in VBA since we have not used Else statement :)

Comment: @Sixthsense Actually, the correct answer is "`End If` is not needed because it is a single-line `If`".  A single-line `If` can contain an `Else`, e.g. `If a = b Then c = 5 Else c = 6`.

Comment: Good to know. I'll remove my comment.

Comment: @YowE3K, Have you tried it?  Please try and comment.

Comment: Don't know who made -1 to me :(

Comment: @Sixthsense Sorry, tried what?  My comment above was agreeing with your statement that the `End If` is not needed, but just not the reason for it (that "we have not used Else statement").  Basically, a single-line `If` does not have an `End If`, while a multi-line `If` (irrespective of whether that multi-line `If` includes an `Else`) **does** require an `End If`.

Comment: @ YowE3K , Sorry, I misunderstood your statement.

Comment: @Sixthsense The -1 wasn't from me.  (Although your code probably still won't work, because I think the wrong sheet is being referred to by `Cells(x, "F")` on the second time through the loop.)

Comment: Have you seen the incremental value x = x+1?

Comment: At the end of the first loop, `Demand_WB.Worksheets("Illuminators")` will be the active sheet.  So the second time through (when `x` is 3) it will be equivalent to `With Demand_WB.Worksheets("Illuminators").Cells(3, "F")`.  You then are activating `OP_wb.Worksheets("Optic Main")` but doing a cut of `Demand_WB.Worksheets("Illuminators").Cells(3, "F").EntireRow`, which is the row you pasted to that sheet the last loop, and pasting it back where it was (or perhaps one row below it?).

Comment: There isn't going to be a good answer for this question until it is rewritten without all the `Activate` and `Select` statements.  It needs to be written to assign the source and destination sheets as `Worksheet` objects, and then just use those objects to refer to what needs to be used.  But I am heading to bed, so I will leave that up to you (or Luuklag) to sort out.

Comment: @YowE3K, Yes I agree with you.  I just wanted to give alternative to Do Until statement since OP is not aware of activecell.  That changes needs to be done at OP's end.  I just wanted to show the method :)